# jquery cycle center text

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I cant center a text if I use jquery cycle, any help please!

```
    <!-- Cycle Script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#text").cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            pause: 1
        });

    });
</script>

<style>

#price2 { 
    text-align:center;
    width: 965;
    height:36px;
}

</style>

<div id="text">
  <p>text 1</p>
  <p>text 2</p>
  <p>text 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a width to your p tag, like so:

```
#text { 
    text-align:center;
    height:36px;
}
p {
    width: 965px;
}
```

Comment: thank you! Kolja that is! I know that it was a problem of the css and not of the jquery cycle plugin! really thanks!